# Getting total calculations from Django database

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to get the 10 cars with the most calculations on them in Django.

`Calculations` model is as follows:

```
class Calculations(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(to=User)
    category = models.CharField(max_length=127)
    make = models.CharField(max_length=127)
    model = models.CharField(max_length=127)
    first_registration = models.CharField(max_length=127)
    body = models.CharField(max_length=127)
    facelift = models.CharField(max_length=127)
    engine = models.CharField(max_length=127)
    drive = models.CharField(max_length=127)
    transmission = models.CharField(max_length=127)
    trim = models.CharField(max_length=127, null=True, blank=True)
    mileage = models.IntegerField()
    vat_inclusive = models.NullBooleanField(null=True)
    price_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    market_days_identical = models.CharField(max_length=6, null=True)
    market_days_similar = models.CharField(max_length=6, null=True)
    sales_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2, null=True)
    sales_price_currency = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True)
    purchase_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2, null=True)
    purchase_price_currency = models.CharField(max_length=10, null=True)
    adjusted_price = models.DecimalField(max_digits=8, decimal_places=2, null=True, blank=True)
    customer = models.ForeignKey(to=Customer, null=True, blank=True, on_delete=models.SET_NULL)
    data = models.TextField(null=True, blank=True)
```

Query that I use is as follows:

```
calculations_list = Calculations.objects.values_list('make', 'model', 'first_registration', 'body', 'facelift', 'engine', 'drive','transmission', 'mileage')
                                .distinct()
                                .annotate(num_calculations=Count('make'))
                                .order_by('-num_calculations')[:10]
```

This query gives me:

```
<QuerySet [
   ('BMW', 'M3', '1/2017', 'SALOON / 4 doors', '2014', 'M3', 'RWD', 'MANUAL ', 70000, 6),
   ('Audi', 'A4', '1/2017', ' SALOON / 4 doors', '2012', '2.0 TDI', 'FWD', 'MANUAL ', 70000, 4),
   ('BMW', '7 series', '1/2017', ' SALOON / 4 doors', '2008', '730 d', 'xDrive FOURWD', 'AUTOMATIC Steptronic', 70000, 4),
   .......
]>
```

**But that is not true.**

When I in the query use

`values_list('make', 'model')`

instead of

`values_list('make', 'model', 'first_registration', 'body', 'facelift', 'engine', 'drive','transmission', 'mileage')`

then I get the right result:

```
<QuerySet [
    ('Audi', 'A3', 7),
    ('Audi', 'A4', 6),
    ('BMW', 'M3', 6),
    ....
]>
```

The correct result is :

```
<QuerySet [
        ('Audi', 'A3', 7),
        ('Audi', 'A4', 6),
        ('BMW', 'M3', 6),
        ....
    ]>
```

But in that result I get only `make, model and number of calculations` but I need all those values : `'make', 'model', 'first_registration', 'body', 'facelift', 'engine', 'drive','transmission', 'mileage'` and that is why I tried to use :

```
calculations_list = Calculations.objects.values_list('make', 'model', 'first_registration', 'body', 'facelift', 'engine', 'drive','transmission', 'mileage')
                                    .distinct()
                                    .annotate(num_calculations=Count('make'))
                                    .order_by('-num_calculations')[:10]
```

What do I do wrong?

Comment: I don't understand your question. What is wrong with the first result? And if the second code gives you the right result, why don't you use that?

Comment: @DanielRoseman Because I need all those values, not only `make and model`. And the problem with the first query is that it gives the wrong result.

Comment: But what is the right result?.

Comment: @DanielRoseman Like I said in the question. The result that I get with the `values_list('make', 'model')` in the query instead of  `values_list('make', 'model', 'first_registration', 'body', 'facelift', 'engine', 'drive','transmission', 'mileage')` is right. But I can't use it because I need all those values...

Answer (score 0):

You should check your query. You have not included "first_registration" field in quotes properly. Use this:

```
values_list('make', 'model', 'first_registration', 'body', 'facelift', 'engine', 'drive','transmission', 'mileage')
```

Comment: That was only typo by copy-paste.

Comment: Maybe the distinct() makes such effort?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the distinct() function.

The distinct() function will select the rows which all fields ('make', 'model', 'first_registration', 'body', 'facelift', 'engine', 'drive','transmission', 'mileage') should be different when you use the query:

```
calculations_list = Calculations.objects.values_list('make', 'model', 'first_registration', 'body', 'facelift', 'engine', 'drive','transmission', 'mileage')
                            .distinct()
                            .annotate(num_calculations=Count('make'))
                            .order_by('-num_calculations')[:10]
```

Same but only for fields('make', 'model') when you use the query:

```
values_list('make', 'model')
```

You can ONLY pass fields in the [distinct(*fields)](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/models/querysets/) function if you are using PostgreSQL as DB, your case should be:

```
distinct('make', 'model')
```

Otherwise what I suggest is that, you may try to select all rows with the fields you want. After that you can write python code to parse the top 10 records if the data is not big.